# Algorithm to find minimum spanning tree for graph with edge weights in {1,2,3}

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, minimum-spanning-tree

I have recently been doing some research into Prims/Kruskals algorithms for finding minimum spanning trees in graphs, and I am interested in the following problem:

***Let G be an undirected graph on n vertices with m edges, such that each edge has a weight w(e) ∈ {1, 2, 3}. Is there an algorithm which finds a minimum spanning tree of G in time O(n+m)?***

Obviously, you could just run Prims on the graph, and you would get a minimum spanning tree, but not in the required time.

I was thinking that we could start by adding every edge with weight 1 to the tree, provided it creates no cycles, as if there is an edge of weight 1 that creates no cycles, then it is preferable to an edge of weight 2 say, and do this in increasing order.

Any help on possible ways to design an algorithm to do this would be appreciated and any implementations (java preferable but any language welcome) would be super helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You're describing a minor variation of Kruskal's algorithm that makes the cost of sorting by weight O(m) for m edges because you only need to put the edges in 3 buckets.

Since the rest of Kruskal's is very nearly O(m) due to the amazing properties of the [disjoint set data structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure), you should be in good shape.

Building the tree itself ought to be O(m) rather than O(n + m) as was your goal because there's no need to process the vertices.  E.g. if you have a few edges on a gazillion vertices, most with no connection, the latter don't need to increase algorithm cost if you're careful about data structure design.

Comment: Thank you for this. I have now understood that I can just adapt Kruskals and have the following:

Using the Union-Find (Disjoint-set) data structure:

For all v in V, MAKE_SET(v);
Sort the edges in non-decreasing order into 3 buckets (each bucket corresponds to a specific edge weight);
For every edge (u,v) in E, starting with those in bucket 1 (ie in the non-decreasing order) { 
if FIND(u) != FIND(v) then T=T U (u,v);
UNION(u,v);
}
Return T

Comment: Does this work in O(m+n) time? If not, would you be able to help where I am misunderstanding/provide some pseudocode? Sorry if I am not understanding

Comment: It works in O(alpha(m)) time. For any purpose in the known universe, alpha(m) < 5m.  So in practice it's O(m).  Your description is fine. "Sorting" isn't in the conventional sense.  It's jsut one pass through the elements assigning each to the right bucket in constant time. @mathcomp

Comment: Thank you, but what about the fact that I went through all vertices in order to do the MAKE_SET(v) for each vertex? Doesnt that then make it O(n+m)?

Comment: @mathcomp You only need to go through the vertices incident to edges. I.e. you can ignore vertices with no edges. Since each edge is incident to only 2 vertices, the algorithm is O(m) if properly implemented.  Note that if your graph doesn't have vertices with no edges, then O(m) subsumes O(n) anyway. In a dense graph O(m) = O(n^2).